# Athena - Decode URL string with trailing escapes

Tags: amazon-athena

I'm trying to decode a url string using the `url_decode()` function, but I get this error.

INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: URLDecoder: Incomplete trailing escape (%) pattern.

I have also tried replacing each encoding like this `replace(url, '%3D', '=')` or `replace(url, '\%3D', '=')` to no avail.

Comment: Can you provide an example URL? Because url_decode() works for me with %.

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the function can't decode certain urls. You can find out which ones by doing

```
select url from mytable where try(url_decode(url)) is null
```

Then you can decide what yo do, either fix the urls using the replace function, for example, or ignore them altogether using the `try` function that will return null in case of errors in the argument.